# GEE: How can I get the Button onClick function to work on each map?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I made a panel on two screens by using the code below. There is in each panel on both screens, a dates selector and a run button for calculating the NDVI and adds results to the map as a layer. However, I don't know how to modify the code so that these panels work independently on the map to which they belong. If you know, can you tell me?

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
          [[[126.7664070152438, 37.70130604607567],
            [126.7664070152438, 37.42698739064678],
            [127.18663406602505, 37.42698739064678],
            [127.18663406602505, 37.70130604607567]]], null, false);

function controlPanel(){

  var Title = ui.Label({value: 'NDVI',style: {fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '16px'}});

  var Year_selector = ui.Select({
    
    items: [
      {label: '2013', value: 2013},
      {label: '2014', value: 2014},
      {label: '2015', value: 2015},
      {label: '2016', value: 2016},
      {label: '2017', value: 2017},
      {label: '2018', value: 2018},
      {label: '2019', value: 2019},
      {label: '2020', value: 2020},
      {label: '2021', value: 2021},
    ],style:{width: '150px'}
  
  }).setPlaceholder('Select year...');
  
  var runButton = ui.Button({label: 'Run', style: {width: '150px'}});
  
  runButton.onClick(function (){
    
    var start_date = Year_selector.getValue() + '-01-01';
    var end_date = Year_selector.getValue() + '-12-31';
    
    var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
            .filterBounds(roi)
            .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
            .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER_LAND', 'less_than', 5)
            .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH',116))
            .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW',34))
            .median();
    
    var L8 = L8.clip(roi);
    
    var nir = L8.select('B5');
    var red = L8.select('B4');
    var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');

    var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
    
    //***********************************************************************
    map1.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, Year_selector.getValue() +' NDVI image');
    map2.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, Year_selector.getValue() +' NDVI image');
    //***********************************************************************
    
  });
  
  var panel = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [Title, Year_selector, runButton],
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical'),
    style:{maxHeight: '90%'}
  });
  
  panel.style().set('position', 'top-left');

  return panel;

}

var map1 = ui.Map();
var map2 = ui.Map();

map1.add(controlPanel());
map2.add(controlPanel());

var linker = ui.Map.Linker([map1, map2]);

map1.setCenter(126.99, 37.55, 10);

map1.setControlVisibility({zoomControl: false, fullscreenControl: false});
map2.setControlVisibility({zoomControl: false, fullscreenControl: false});

var mapPanel = ui.Panel([ui.Panel(map1, null, {stretch:'both'}),ui.Panel(map2, null, {stretch:'both'})], ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'), {stretch:'both'});

ui.root.widgets().reset([mapPanel]);
ui.root.setLayout(ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('vertical'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For working independently each screen, you need to create a second **controlPanel** function and delete (see lines below) **map2.addLayer** at the first function and **map1.addLayer** at the second function.

```
//***********************************************************************
map1.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, Year_selector.getValue() +' NDVI image');
map2.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, Year_selector.getValue() +' NDVI image');
//***********************************************************************
```

Code looks as follows:

```
 var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
              [[[126.7664070152438, 37.70130604607567],
                [126.7664070152438, 37.42698739064678],
                [127.18663406602505, 37.42698739064678],
                [127.18663406602505, 37.70130604607567]]], null, false);


function controlPanel1(){

  var Title = ui.Label({value: 'NDVI',style: {fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '16px'}});

  var Year_selector = ui.Select({
    
    items: [
      {label: '2013', value: 2013},
      {label: '2014', value: 2014},
      {label: '2015', value: 2015},
      {label: '2016', value: 2016},
      {label: '2017', value: 2017},
      {label: '2018', value: 2018},
      {label: '2019', value: 2019},
      {label: '2020', value: 2020},
      {label: '2021', value: 2021},
    ],style:{width: '150px'}
  
  }).setPlaceholder('Select year...');
  
  var runButton = ui.Button({label: 'Run', style: {width: '150px'}});
  
  runButton.onClick(function (){
    
    var start_date = Year_selector.getValue() + '-01-01';
    var end_date = Year_selector.getValue() + '-12-31';
    
    var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
            .filterBounds(roi)
            .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
            .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER_LAND', 'less_than', 5)
            .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH',116))
            .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW',34))
            .median();
    
    L8 = L8.clip(roi);
    
    var nir = L8.select('B5');
    var red = L8.select('B4');
    var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');

    var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
    
    //***********************************************************************
    map1.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, Year_selector.getValue() +' NDVI image');
    //***********************************************************************
    
  });
  
  var panel = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [Title, Year_selector, runButton],
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical'),
    style:{maxHeight: '90%'}
  });
  
  panel.style().set('position', 'top-left');

  return panel;

}

function controlPanel2(){

  var Title = ui.Label({value: 'NDVI',style: {fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '16px'}});

  var Year_selector = ui.Select({
    
    items: [
      {label: '2013', value: 2013},
      {label: '2014', value: 2014},
      {label: '2015', value: 2015},
      {label: '2016', value: 2016},
      {label: '2017', value: 2017},
      {label: '2018', value: 2018},
      {label: '2019', value: 2019},
      {label: '2020', value: 2020},
      {label: '2021', value: 2021},
    ],style:{width: '150px'}
  
  }).setPlaceholder('Select year...');
  
  var runButton = ui.Button({label: 'Run', style: {width: '150px'}});
  
  runButton.onClick(function (){
    
    var start_date = Year_selector.getValue() + '-01-01';
    var end_date = Year_selector.getValue() + '-12-31';
    
    var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
            .filterBounds(roi)
            .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
            .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER_LAND', 'less_than', 5)
            .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH',116))
            .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW',34))
            .median();
    
    L8 = L8.clip(roi);
    
    var nir = L8.select('B5');
    var red = L8.select('B4');
    var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');

    var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
    
    //***********************************************************************
    map2.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, Year_selector.getValue() +' NDVI image');
    //***********************************************************************
    
  });
  
  var panel = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [Title, Year_selector, runButton],
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical'),
    style:{maxHeight: '90%'}
  });
  
  panel.style().set('position', 'top-left');

  return panel;

}

var map1 = ui.Map();
var map2 = ui.Map();

map1.add(controlPanel1());
map2.add(controlPanel2());

var linker = ui.Map.Linker([map1, map2]);

map1.setCenter(126.99, 37.55, 10);

map1.setControlVisibility({zoomControl: false, fullscreenControl: false});
map2.setControlVisibility({zoomControl: false, fullscreenControl: false});

var mapPanel = ui.Panel([ui.Panel(map1, null, {stretch:'both'}),ui.Panel(map2, null, {stretch:'both'})], ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'), {stretch:'both'});

ui.root.widgets().reset([mapPanel]);
ui.root.setLayout(ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('vertical'));
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, it can be observed in following picture that panels work independently of each other.

[image]